# Residual Linear Regressions (No Intercept) Cumulative RSquare

Tags: python, numpy, regression, linear-regression, statsmodels

Looking to Compute Cumulative RSquare on Residual Regressions

Let's say, we are doing Linear Regression with no intercept

Step 1 - `Y ~ b1x1 + e1`

Step 2 - `e1 ~ b2x2 + e2`

Step 3 - `e2 ~ b3x3 + e3`

What's the Cumulative R Square on Step 2 and Step 3?

- Can I assume the cumulative R Square after Step 2 as

`Y ~ X2 + E2` where `X2 = b1x1 + b2x2`

- Similarly, the cumulative R Square after Step 3 as

`Y ~ X3 + E3` where `X3 = b1x1 + b2x2 + b3x3`

or based on assuming I don't want an intercept, would it be like -

- After Step 2 -  `1 - np.sum(e1 ** 2) / np.sum(Y ** 2)`
- After Step 3 -  `1 - np.sum(e3 ** 2) / np.sum(Y ** 2)`

Thanks in advance